# TS2536: Cannot be used as index, even though type is necessarily a key?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add types to this function:

```
setKey(key: keyof TData|string|string[], value: typeof key extends keyof TData ? TData[typeof key] : any) {
    this.set(setIn(key,value));
}
```

Basically `key` should be a `keyof TData`, but it also accepts `fancy.dotted.syntax` and `['array','path','syntax']` which is just too difficult to type properly -- but if you *do* supply a simple index, then I'd like type completions for the value as well. I thought I could use a conditional type for that, but maybe the TS compiler can't handle this? Or did I do it wrong?

Basically, I was hoping the `typeof key extends keyof TData ?` would narrow the scope for the type of `key` so that what follows would work, but TS still thinks it might be a `string|string[]`.

[image: typeof keyof]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof key` will always be the declared type `keyof TData|string|string[]` regardless of what you pass into the function. You want to capture call site types, to do this you need to use a type parameter (constrained to extend `keyof TData|string|string[]`).

```
class DataOwner<TData> {
  setKey<TKey extends keyof TData|string|string[]>(key: TKey, value: TKey extends keyof TData ? TData[TKey] : unknown) {
  }
}

let o = new DataOwner<{ a: string }>();
o.setKey("a", "") // ok 
o.setKey("a", 1) // errr
o.setKey("x", 1) // ok, since key can be any aritrary string
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwHkDuA7ApgJwDwBV4kA+aAbwChpoJMEBpTATwMaekwA8FN0ATGAGtmAewBm0QojAAfCAmwBLdAHM5C5SoDaAXWIAKYUwBcktgBpoANzAgArplP42HbrwHQj4yUTDQA-D7SWs7MOtCmduiC6CIYAJTkVNAAvhRpFCB00CLQALzQWKhw0mhYeGTQYKbySqqpBvEA3BQiAHS0DMz6AERgPZY9PYkA9CM5gtCtHXRsvf2WAIyj4zjY2NOdcz2cA9DL0GMTlhDKwJiezNDAYOjQAEYXt+xgSgqv7LWa0EA)

The value of this is limited IMO. Since `key` can be any string, passing in anything that is not a key will not error in any way.

Also since `TKey` can be `string` you will not get suggestions in spite of it also extending `keyof TData`. Multiple overloads will work better with regard to key suggestion, but still suffer from the first issue I pointed out:

```
class DataOwner<TData> {
  setKey<TKey extends keyof TData>(key: TKey, value: TData[TKey]): void
  setKey(key: string|string[], value: unknown): void
  setKey(key: keyof TData|string|string[], value: unknown) {
  }
}

let o = new DataOwner<{ a: string }>();
o.setKey("a", "") // ok 
o.setKey("a", 1) // errr
o.setKey("x", 1) // ok, since key can be any arbitrary string
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwHkDuA7ApgJwDwBV4kA+aAbwChpoJMEBpTATwMaekwA8FN0ATGAGtmAewBm0QojDEAFMKYAuSWwA00AG5gQAV0zKpSANr42AXQCUyjSICWfKjTpt5zZRATZb6AOYAfDy9fIzN1LV19aB10QXQRDCtNOwdqWgZmVyVoBXFJIjAAz29-QOKQsO09ZWjY+PQLckcAXwoWihA6aBFoAF5oLFQ4aTQsPDJoMHci32gmuQsAbgoRADo0lwAiMA31DY2GgHoDrsFoZbXnDK2d6ABGQ+OcbGxz9avOG-voI5P1CG9gJhssxoMAwOhoAAjIHg9hgLyeeHsUozIA)

**Edit** As pointed out in the comments overloads don't work well here because if the value does not match the compiler moves on to the string overloads and the will match for sure since `value` is `unknown`, the first option is the closest we are going to get.

Comment: PhpStorm still gives suggestions: https://i.imgur.com/TXuhC9c.png The overloading does seem to work better though. I would have thought those two solutions would be equivalent?

Comment: Oh no -- I see the difference now. With the overloaded one, it can match *any* of the overloads *even if* `key` is a real keyof TData. With the first solution, if key is a real keyof TData, then the value *must* match the proper type. The overload solution catches fewer errors! https://go.mpen.ca/4dfkh

Comment: @mpen wops, yeah I didn't account for the way overload resolution moves on to the next overload if it fails to match the first one. With the single signature version, `TKey` is inferred and then `value` is checked. If `value` fails it the call is marked as error no next overload to move on to